# Arc length in Euclidean Space

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have a formula for the arc length in Euclidean space $$L=\int^b _a \sqrt{\bigg |g_{ij} \frac{dx^i}{dt} \frac{dx^j}{dt}\bigg|} \, dt$$

What is $g_{ij}$?

Answer (score 2):

The quantities $g_{ij}$ should be the components of the metric tensor, i.e. a bilinear form $g$ defined on the tangent space of your manifold which defines the metric.

In the case of an euclidean plane the tangent space can be identified with the plane itself and $g$ reduces to the identity, i.e. $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$.